# TypeORM error - DataTypeNotSupportedError

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

My entity file: user.ts:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number | undefined;

  @Column({ type: 'string', name: 'username', nullable: true })
  username: string | undefined;

  @Column()
  password: string | undefined;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date | undefined;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date | undefined;
}
```

I'm getting the following error: `'Data type "string" in "User.username" is not supported by "mysql" database.'`

Tried to search within typeorm issues tracker on a github, but there was no answers that would solve this issue. I run my project using `tsc-watch`

Comment: mysql doesn't have a `string` type, but it does have a `varchar` and `text` type, so you can use those instead

Comment: Thanks! But is it ok to leave in the code `username: string | undefined` it would use a type from a decorator, right? But, if it's used from a decorator, why do we have to set a type in a code then? Drop an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Those are two different types, the one you define in `@Column` is for your database (eg mysql), and the one in your property is for Typescript. You could leave out the type in the decorator, since TypeORM can infer it's database type from it, but if you leave out the one in your property declaration. Then Typescript won't know what the type of that property is (so you won't have autocompletion or typechecking on it)

Comment: It's all clear now, ty vm.

Comment: @AlexanderKim what did you end up doing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct usage:

```
@Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
username: string | undefined;
```